# Some distorted islands after UV unwrapping

Tags: uv

I faced such a strange issue after applying the Unwrap command.
As far as I can tell, the mesh geometry is fine here but somehow some of the UV's are not aligned as I expect them to be. You can see one of them in the image below, under the green rectangle.
Does someone know how can I avoid this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you unwarp try change method from Angle Based(default) to Conformal or uncheck Fill Holes
[More About Unwarp Options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/mapping_types.html#unwrap)

With Fill Holes:
[image: With Fill Holes]

Without Fill Holes:
[image: Without Fill Holes]